# Edit book links in formula with VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have template book with some formulas in cells. This formulas links to some books, like
='\path\DATA[wsName.xlsm]Discription'!$E$13

I want to change this link "\path\DATA[wsName.xlsm]" to another link. But it doesn't work.

```
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks 'Getting path from another opened workbook
    If wb.name Like "1.0*" Then
        newAddress = wb.path & "\[" & wb.name & "]" 'GET NEW LINK
    End If
Next

Dim ttt As String
ttt = "\\path\DATA\[wsName.xlsm]"
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    .Replace What:=ttt, _
    Replacement:=newAddress, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

This code works normally:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    .Replace What:=ttt, _
    Replacement:="TEST STRING", _  'Change to text, instead of newAddress
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

What's wrong with my newAddress? I think it's work like that, because book, which name i want to get, already open...
Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 0):

```
newAddress = "[" & wb.name & "]"
```

This helped me.